# Endpoint Basic Auth VueJs

Tags: http, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

I am trying to access an endpoint with username and password but the console give me a 401()

this is my code:

```
created () {
    this.$http.get(URL, {
        username: 'xxxxxxx',
        password: 'xxxxx'
     }).then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
 }
```

Is it the correct way to access an endpoint with VueJS?

Comment: What kind of username/password protection does it have? Http authentication, login page, etc?

Comment: There is no vue correct way. Vue focus is rendering (vue). You can access an endpoint whatever you want to (axios, jquery, vue resource).

Comment: Only i have this endpoint because this is antes exercise and they give me the username and password. The exercise says get the list through endpoint protected.

Comment: @Lucas Marqués, could you send me and example or a link to see how can i access?

Comment: @rubotero, sure thing. But I need to know how the endpoint is protected. Basic auth ? Session ?

Comment: This is a protected endpoint; provide the following credentials using the basic auth mechanism, username - xxx and password - xxx

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the username and password codified in Base64.

```
const encodedUserPswd = btoa(`${user}:${pswd}`);
axios.get(URL, {}, {
  headers: { `Authorization: Basic ${encodedUserPswd}` },
}).then((response) => {
  // ...
});
```